# Stop mpg123 without being in its shell?

Tags: 12.04, music, mp3

I'm using `mpg123` to play a list of MP3 files through my intercom using a home server on Ubuntu 12.04. I'm using this command:

```
mpg123 *.mp3 --loop 0 &
```

With the `&` appended because I'd like to be able to close my SSH window and have the music keep playing.

However, I haven't been able to find a way to make the music stop when I want it to. Is there a way for a cron job to come back hours later and kill the music? If anyone has alternative players that would allow me to do this, that would be great too!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you will only have 1 command active at a given time. Then ...

```
pkill mpg123
```

will kill all instances of mpg123 in the process list.

pkill it not very friendly though. An alternative:

```
pidof mpg123 | xargs kill -9
```

With `ps -ef | grep mpg123` you can find the process number and use

```
killall -9 {processnumber}
```

to kill 1 instance. I'll omit the longer versions ;)

Comment: What do you mean by it 'not being very friendly'?

Comment: I mean by that that you can not tell it to kill 1 of 2 instances of a particular thing you want to kill.

Comment: It will just kill all of them, right? That's what I'd like, actually.

Comment: Then the 1st command works and is the easiest one ;)